# General solutions of ordinary differential equations, Wronskian test

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have just started learning about differential equations, and there is one thing that is unclear to me.

If we want to know whether a set of solutions constitutes the general solutions or not, is it enough to use the Wronskian test, or do we also have to check if the solutions satisfy the equation?

For example:

$L=D^2-2aD+a^2, Lx=0, h_1(t)=e^{at}$, $h_2(t)=... $

Do I need to show:

$Lx=0 \implies (D^2-2aD+a^2)e^{at}=0: a^2e^{at}-2a^2e^{at}+a^2e^{at}=0 \implies correct$

Or is the Wronskian test enough to say that $h_1(t)=e^{at}$, $h_2(t)=... $ are general solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are given a set of solutions then you do not need to check to see if they are solutions; it is a given.
2. If you have a set of all solutions, then the general solution is a linear combination of the solutions.  For example if you know that the differential equation is second order (as in your example) and that $y=e^{at}$ and $y=e^{bt}$ are solutions then the general solution is $y = C_1 e^{at} + C_2 e^{bt}$
3. If you want to know if the solutions you are given are linearly independent or not, then using the Wronskian would help you discover that.

Comment: Thank you, Paul! It was exactly this that I wanted to know. I appreciate it!